# Sass | Mixin for handling arrays

Tags: arrays, list, sass

Hello people can anyone help with solving this issue I have, from the
code bellow you can see that I got something but the thing i want is
to make border property from three different arrays and combine theirsnth indexes...

```
$borderWidth: 1px 2px 3px;
$borderStyle: 'solid' 'dashed' 'groovy';
$borderColor: 'red' 'green' 'yellow';

@mixin makeBorderFromArrays($lists...) {
    $listOfLists: length($lists);

    @for $i from 1 through length($lists){

      $array: nth($lists,$i);

      .array-#{$i}{array:$array;}

        @for $j from 1 through length($array){

          $arrayItem: nth($array,$j);

          .array-#{$i}-itemNumber-#{$j}{array-item:$arrayItem;}
        }
    }
}
@include makeBorderFromArrays($borderWidth, $borderStyle, $borderColor);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible when you use a multidimensional array or array of arrays?

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: 3 border property values : 1px solid red, 2px dashed green,3px groovy yellow..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the result you're looking for but maybe you can try the following. If it isn't the result you want then just let me know.

```
    $borders: (
        0: (
            width: 1px,
            type: 'solid',
            color: 'red'
        ),
        1: (
            width: 2px,
            type: 'dashed',
            color: 'green'
        ),
        2: (
            width: 3px,
            type: 'groovy',
            color: 'yellow'
        ),
    );

@mixin makeBorderFromArray($borders) {    
    @each $i, $border in $borders {    
        .array-#{$i} {
            border: map-get( $border , width ) unquote( map-get( $border, type ) )  unquote( map-get( $border, color ) );    
        }
    }
}

@include makeBorderFromArray($borders);
```

This should return the following CSS:

```
.array-0 {
  border: 1px solid red; }

.array-1 {
  border: 2px dashed green; }

.array-2 {
  border: 3px groovy yellow; }
```

Comment: does not rork, did you even checked it?

Comment: @muecas yes I've checked and it worked. Maybe there is some difference between SCSS and Sass I'm not aware of? But can you define what isn't working?

Comment: @muecas can you tell what "this does not work" mean. I mean it doesn't tell me what goes wrong

Comment: Output: `(width: 1px, type: "solid", color: "red") isn't a valid CSS value.`

Comment: @muecas Sorry that isn't the output I'm getting

Comment: @muecas when removing the top comment and set the compiler to libSass it just works. Could it be something version related or maybe ruby vs node Sass compiler?

Comment: no, there are no syntax differences between compilers.

Comment: @muecas how about if you delete the line:  `@warn $border;`?

Comment: @muecas to me it looks like sassmeister outputs the `@warn` as CSS instead of the actual CSS you want. So I'm just wondering if that fixes it for you

Comment: Yes probably its just that. Glad you fixed your code :)

Comment: This is get with maps, and code works, but I need to build 3 border properties from 3 different arrays and basicly i want to mimic zip() function method only going manualy..

Comment: @StevanStojanovic why would you want to create a function when the function you need is already there?

Comment: @SuperDJ To have more programming approach to solve the problem.. :)